# Using Ref inside Fn::Sub in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use `fn::sub` with a Ref inside it.

I have a string "Comment xyz ${NAME}". This string comes as a parameter to the stack. Say the parameter name is "test".

I would now like to replace the ${NAME} in the string using `fn::sub` function inside the Cloudformation script.

```
fn::sub:[{"Ref":"test"},{"NAME":"balaji"}]
```

**Expected output** is "Comment xyz balaji".

However, this is the error I am getting:

> Template validation error: Template error: One or more Fn::Sub
>   intrinsic functions don't specify expected arguments. Specify a string
>   as first argument, and an optional second argument to specify a
>   mapping of values to replace in the string

Let me know what needs to be fixed here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html), the first parameter in `Fn::Sub` must be:

> A string with variables that AWS CloudFormation substitutes with their associated values at runtime. Write variables as ${MyVarName}. Variables can be template parameter names, resource logical IDs, resource attributes, or a variable in a key-value map. **If you specify only template parameter names, resource logical IDs, and resource attributes, don't specify a key-value map.**

(Emphasis added.)

Thus, it is (at the time of writing) impossible to do this.

If you had a parameter:

```
"test": {
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "Comment xyz ${NAME}"
}
```

And then a substitution:

```
"Fn::Sub": ["${test}", {"NAME": "balaji"}]
```

The substitution would yield the literal string `Comment xyz ${NAME}`.

Comment: How to "fix it" in this case would be to use Fn::Join instead.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html

Comment: For the YAML folks out there here is an example for a Tags element on a Security Group that uses two parameters: 
```Value: !Sub ${InstanceTagName}-sg-${Environment}```

Answer (score 0):

I have no tried Fn::Sub, however these syntaxes work:

```
SubnetIds:
  Fn::Split: [ ",", Ref: subnetsInternal]
```

and

```
EnvironmentName: 
  !Join ["", [Ref: applicationName, "-env"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

yaml version:

`!Sub '${test} ${NAME}'`